# Prevent jQuery from selecting multiple items with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a post feed where a play button can be clicked and the play button will be toggled to a pause button, however, when I click on one of the play buttons, both pause buttons are toggled on (for each post). How do I only allow Javascript to toggle the single play button on the feed when there are multiple classes with the same name on the page.

What it looks like after I click the top play button (both pause buttons are toggled when only the top one should change):

[image: Both pause buttons are toggled]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="media-circle">
<!-- the pause icon is display: none at start -->
   <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause feed-pause"></i>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
jQuery('.media-circle').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play');
    jQuery('.feed-pause').toggle();
    //this controls universal bottom bar play button
    jQuery('#bottom-play-button-container').find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play').toggleClass('ion-pause'); 
});
```

Here is the JS for the bottom play button (fairly similar) EDIT*

```
jQuery('#bottom-play-button-container').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play').toggleClass('ion-pause');
    jQuery('#play-pause-toggle').find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play').toggleClass('ion-pause');

    jQuery('.media-circle').find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play');
    jQuery('.feed-pause').toggle();

});
```

Comment: Why not use the same technique you're already using in the line above the `.feed-pause` line?

Comment: Why can't you just use an `id`? Or really anything that there's only one of

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard because this will be a dynamic feed with hundreds of songs that are constantly changing. I wouldn't know how to dynamically change the ID in the HTML and JS if that makes sense?

Comment: Just update the `id` on click with JavaScript. Totally possible, in fact that kind of thing is basically what JavaScript was made for. I'll update with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $album = $('.album-dark-overlay'),
  $bottombutton = $('#bottom-play-button-container'),
  $last_player = null; // This will be the last player playing, we need it to continue the playing after the general player changes manually from play to pause

$album.click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  // Toggle any play class to pause from other elements playing.
  $album.filter('.pause').not(this).toggleClass('play pause');

  //Toggle general button in the same way.
  if ($(this).hasClass('pause')) {

    $bottombutton.removeClass('pause').addClass('play');

  } else {

    $bottombutton.removeClass('play').addClass('pause');

  }

  // Toggle the class from pause to play and from play to pause
  $(this).toggleClass('play pause');

  // Update variable to this player
  $last_player = $(this);

});

$bottombutton.click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  // Check if the #bottombutton has class .pause and pause all playing players
  if ($bottombutton.hasClass('pause')) {

    // Toggle the class from pause to play and from play to pause
    $album.filter('.pause').toggleClass('play pause');

    // Check if the $last_player was assigned at least once.
  } else if ($last_player !== null) {

    $last_player.toggleClass('play pause');

  }

  $bottombutton.toggleClass('play pause');

});
```

```css
.album-dark-overlay,
#bottom-play-button-container {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

#bottom-play-button-container {
  background-color: pink;
}

.play .ion-pause {
  display: none;
}

.pause .ion-ios-play {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album-dark-overlay play">
  <div class="media-circle">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause feed-pause"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="album-dark-overlay play">
  <div class="media-circle">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause feed-pause"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bottom-play-button-container" class="play">
  <!--<a id="media-toggle-bottom" href="">-->
  <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause"></i>
  <!--</a>-->
</div>
```

---

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg8d66sm/1/) is a general code but it might help you understand better how, in my opinion, you could approach it and it should be easy to adapt.

There are some [UX aspects](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) that I'm assuming:

- If a singular player is playing, when the user clicks play button of a second player the first player pauses.
- If a player starts playing the #general_button changes to pause also. When the user clicks the general (pause now) button the individual player pauses. Clicking again the general (play now) button starts playing the previous singular player.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Both of your UX assumptions are correct. Looking at the first function, Im not sure the button1 and button2 process would work since this feed will be dynamic and be host to a whole list of songs so I wouldnt just be able to hardcode a specific number of buttons into that. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's just an example of any children element you would like to change the class. I actually would apply the pause/play class to the container. Let me edit the code to include these.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro thanks for you help thus far. A bit stuck though, here's a fiddle with code (this is just for easy retrieval of code, it doesnt work). When I now click a feed play button, it completely disappears. If I click another feed play button, that one disappears and the old one reappears. The general bottom play button will display both the pause and play buttons. So a couple issues, where did I go wrong exactly? thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/c0fy2j1u/1/

Comment: If you could make a JSFiddle with the CSS it would be much easier to solve it as we could see the actual undesired result and fix it accordingly. Because right now you have 2 icons inside each media-circle, and Im not sure if both should change class and to which class each.

Comment: ah you're right, here's the updated code. I added the segment of the stylesheet that relates to the playpause. Let me know if there's something else you need: https://jsfiddle.net/c0fy2j1u/3/

Comment: sorry to bother you, did you have an opportunity to check out the fiddle?

Comment: No problem :) let me see.

Comment: thank you! Let me know if I can provide any more information

Comment: So the `<i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause feed-pause"></i>` are the play and pause buttons that should be toggled simultaneously?

Comment: yes those are for the feed buttons, those two icons should toggle (one to off and one to on) if either the icon is clicked in the feed (for one of the songs) or if the play/pause icon is clicked on the bottom bar. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131617/discussion-between-alvaro-and-jordan-lewallen).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `children()` method. Read more here: https://api.jquery.com/children/

```
jQuery('.media-circle').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).children('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play');
    jQuery(this).children('.feed-pause').toggle();
    //this controls universal bottom bar play button
    jQuery('#bottom-play-button-container').find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play').toggleClass('ion-pause'); 
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, great fix. Follow up question though. So I have a universal play button at the bottom of my page. When clicked it toggles the icons in the feed. So if I were to click play in the feed, I'd have post1 = pauseicon and post2 = playicon. Now if I clicked the bottom play/pause button, the icons would toggle to post1=playicon post2=pauseicon. What would be the best way to toggle only the element that this is a pause icon back to a play button. If that makes sense? The way I have programmed the bottom button works great for only one post. I'll update my post with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign something unique to the element that gets clicked, you can do this by removing any other instances that came before it before assigning it.

Here's the gist of it:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>hjkl</div>
  <div>qwer</div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container div {
  padding: 10px;
}

#active {
  background: red;
}
```

```
$("#container div").click(function(){
    $("#container div").removeAttr("id");

  $(this).attr("id", "active");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2fgyq1sL/